# Função recursiva para retornar string ao contrário

Tags: python

Preciso de uma **função recursiva que retorne a string que recebe como parâmetro de forma invertida**,cheguei nessa função:

```
def stringinvert(palavra):
    if palavra < 10:
        print(palavra)
        return stringinvert(palavra[::-1])

print(stringinvert('teste'))
```

Porém gera um erro que no caso é esse aqui:

```
if palavra < 10:

    TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Bem,isso pra mim já era previsível. A questão é: o passo recursivo é a string ter apenas uma letra,ou seja,eu retorno apenas essa letra,o problema é como vou criar essa condição em Python ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O erro está a acontecer porque estás verificar se "teste" (string) é menor que 10 (???), acho que o que queres é o comprimento da string (número de caracteres):

```
...
if len(palavra) < 10:
...
```

Mas mesmo assim não ia resultar, entrando em ciclo infinito caso o comprimento da string fosse menor que 10 caracteres, ou retornando `None` se fosse 10 ou mais caracteres.

Para fazeres a inversão da string usando recursividade podes:

```
def reverse_str(s):
    if s == '':
        return s # retornar invertida
    return s[-1] + reverse_str(s[:-1]) # concatenar o ultimo caracter com o resto da string excepto o ultimo

print(reverse_str('aeiou')) # uoiea
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/ColorfulPassionateObservatory)

Nota que isto faz-se apenas por motivos pedagógicos, porque no 'mundo real' o melhor a fazer é:

```
'aeiou'[::-1]
```

Comment: Sempre aprendendo, desconhecia `[::-1]`. Já agora, pode explicar a diferença entre `[:]` e `[::]`? :)

Comment: @lazyFox, vê desta forma, `lista[index_start:index_end:step]`, e em que o step pode ser negativo, gerando a lista invertida no caso de ser `-1`. Aqui tens explicações mais completas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel :) muito útil esse link.

Answer (score 0):

Está retornando esse erro porque a 'palavra' é um string e não um número para utilizar um comparador como o menor que (<).

Nesse caso basta adiciona a função 'len' que ira retornar o tamanho da string.

Segue código abaixo:

```
def stringinvert(palavra):
    if len(palavra) < 10:
        print(palavra)
        return stringinvert(palavra[::-1])

print(stringinvert('teste'))
```

Comment: Para constar, deixei meu negativo pois a solução está errada. Apenas adicionar o `len` não resolveu o problema. Sua função recursiva não possui condição de parada, fazendo com que fique em recursão infinitamente, além de não fazer sentido o código.

Comment: Anderson, minha resposta foi exatamente na dúvida do nosso colega. A qual eu tinha o conhecimento de resposta, quanto a não recursividade não havia visto tal problema. A questão de a resposta não afetar esse dois pontos é porque não foi requisitado, não sei até que ponto isso merece negativação. Mas compreendo seu posicionamento e obrigado pelo feeback

Comment: Não negativei, mas tá com erro: `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: Clayton,como eu disse ali em cima,o erro eu já esperava o que eu não sabia era como transformar isso em Python de forma a não retornar o erro.O problema é que essa sua solução não dá um caso base pra função recursiva,exatamente o que o Anderson disse.Abraço!